# Convert a selection to TeXForm, then copy to clipboard

Tags: latex

I've been trying to find a way to make a keyboard shortcut to copy a selection of mathematica code to tex form, then copy it to my clipboard, since right clicking-> copy as-> LaTeX is very tedious. I can speed this process up a little by right clicking->Y->L, but it's still quite tedious. I can do this for the last output, but I have to type

```
    CopyToClipboard[TeXForm[%]]
```

which is also quite tedious.

Additionally, I can select an input OR output cell and copy as LaTeX, but I cannot do both at the same time. This is annoying if I want to show the input as LaTeX, and then the answer, for example when integrating:

```
    In[34]:= Integrate[Sin[x], {x, -10, 6}]

    Out[34]= -Cos[6] + Cos[10]
```

I have previously been selecting the integrate cell, right clicking copy as LaTeX and repeating for the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be helpful:

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[]
 ,
 DockedCells -> {
  Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[
   Button[
    "copy as tex",
    SelectionMove[ButtonNotebook[], Previous, CellGroup];
    FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX[]
   ]]]]}]
```

If your insertion point is right below the input/output cell group, then clicking the button (which should be showing up in a docked cell at the top of the notebook) will briefly select that input/output cell group and copy them as TeX. I tested this on Windows (version 10.3) and it should work on any recent version of Mathematica.

If this is useful you can make a few improvements: Change `EvaluationNotebook[]` to `$FrontEnd` to have the docked cell appear on any notebook. Also: create addition buttons which move the selection to only the previous output cell or only the previous input cell.

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: This is definitely an improvement! I thought about using a button, but lacked the knowledge to create it, so thank you! Is there a way I could automatically include "\\" between the two lines?